# Is a right angle triangle possible?

Tags: c, math

Given `h`, the hypotenuse and `s`, the surface area, it is asked to print the sides of the right angle triangle if possible, else print `-1`. So here was my approach;

```
   double h,s;
   scanf("%lf %lf",&h,&s);
   s*=4;
   double squaresum=(h*h) + s;
   double squarediff=(h*h) - s;
   if(squarediff<0)
       printf("-1\n");
   else
   {
       double a = sqrt(squaresum)+sqrt(squarediff);
       a/=2;
       double b = sqrt(squaresum)-sqrt(squarediff);
       b/=2;
       if(h>=a+b)
            printf("-1\n");
       else
        printf("%.6lf %.6lf %.6lf\n",h,a,b);
   }
```

My approach:
Given `s`, if we multiply `4`, then it is `2*a*b`, where `a` and `b` are the other sides of the triangle. Then I find `(a+b)^2` and `(a-b)^2` as I have `h*h=a^2+b^2`.
It even passed the custom test case:

```
4
5 6
6 10
258303 89837245228
616153 77878145466
```

Output:

```
4.000000 3.000000 5.000000
-1
-1
546189.769984 285168.817674 616153.000000
```

But the answer is being judged as wrong. I am not able to pick up how the answer could go wrong given `0<=h<=10^9` and `0<=s<=10^12`.
The problem link-
https://www.codechef.com/problems/RIGHTTRI

Comment: precision.. precision.. precision.. Might not be that, but it is a highly suspect. Try to make the comparisons with a delta.

Comment: @bolov The precision was given to be at least of the order `0.01`, and I have printed it up to 6 decimals.....so will precision be a factor here..??

Comment: it can be. In the comparisons. For instance if in you program `h` is `5.9999` and `a+b` is `6.0001` then the difference between them is `0.0002` which is well bellow the precision you have been given, meaning they should be considered equal and so the triangle possible, but in your code considers them not `>=` which will output `-1`. In every comparison you should factor in a delta of `0.01`

Comment: @bolov the judge asked for `0.01` accuracy while printing the sides......but it should always be calculated with max precission so in your given case , the answer I guess should be `-1` .....correct me if I m wrong!..I have added the problem link in the question...

Comment: @yobro97 What @bolov is trying to say is that if you get a `h` and a `s` such that `h = 6.0001` and `a + b = 5.9999`, a right triangle is possible, but your code will print `-1` because of `h >= a + b`. You should do a test such as `h - (a + b) >= 0.01` if the judge asked for a `0.01` accuracy.

Comment: when you are dealing with floating points numbers you get rounding errors. The value stored in the result will differ from the *mathematical* accurate result. You need to take this into consideration always when dealing with floating point numbers.

Comment: Your code looks good to me. I took your code and added a few more lines to recompute `h` and `s` from `a` and `b`, and then added `printf` lines to print the input `h` and `s` and computed `h` and `s`. They are pretty close. See http://ideone.com/Vsmre9.

Comment: There's no precision issue with the `if(squarediff<0)` check, and I think the  `if(h>a+b)` check is unnecessary, but harmless. So the only issue is the one that SuperPeanut pointed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I'm wrong, but if I read the Output required :

> Output the answer for each test-case in a single line. If it is not possible to find such a triangle, output -1. Otherwise print 3 real numbers corresponding to the lengths of the sides of the triangle **sorted in non-decreasing order**. Please note that the length of the triangle sides should not differ by more than 0.01 in absolute value from the correct lengths.

Your output is not sorted... I guess non-decreasing order means increasing order... Maybe give it a shot before anything else...

(Edited question according to comment) :

non-decreasing order means you must sort them number from the lowest to the highest, by length :

3.000000 4.000000 5.000000

Mainly the issue with math problems is to understand what they want from you...